# "Pudency" vs "Pudicity"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing a text about relation of social moral and body shame, and I am kind of lost in vocabulary.

I am looking for a word which means at the same time:

- Tendency to hide body from exposure
- General modesty
- Tendency to feel ashamed
- Non-sexualized behavior

And also the term must be well recognized and widely used.

I have found two words so far, both seem to be close: "**pudency**" and "**pudicity**". I cannot understand the difference, so I cannot choose the right one.

Can anybody please, explain me the difference?

Or maybe suggest some other words close in meaning?

**Update**

From the answer below, now I see that sticking to those pu* words was definitely a mistake. Now I am more interested **to find the right word instead**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various *pud-* words from Latin *pudīcitia* will likely be recognizable only to English readers who are also speakers of Modern Romance or scholars of Ancient Latin, or both.

<sub>(Well, perhaps except for *pudenda*, but I can’t guarantee that folks will know **why** it means what it means; folk etymologies abound.)</sub>

For alternatives, “a sense of *modesty, shyness, bashfulness, reticence, decency, chastity, shame, shamefulness”* are all in common use and some may well apply, depending on your intent.

---

From the OED:

> ## *pudency*
>
> **Frequency** (in current use): Band 2 contains words which occur fewer than 0.01 times per million words in typical modern English usage. **These are almost exclusively terms which are not part of normal discourse and would be unknown to most people.** Many are technical terms from specialized discourses. Examples taken from the most frequently attested part of the band include *decanate*, *ennead*, and *scintillometer* (nouns), *geogenic, abactinal* (adjectives), *absterge* and *satinize* (verbs). In the lower frequencies of the band, words are uniformly strange or exotic, e.g. *smother-kiln, haver-cake*, and *sprunt* (nouns), *hidlings, unwhigged, supersubtilized*, and *gummose* (adjectives), *pantle, cloit*, and *stoothe* (verbs), *lawnly, acoast*, and *acicularly* (adverbs), *whethersoever* (conjunction).
>
> About 45% of all non-obsolete OED entries are in Band 2.
>
> **Origin**: A borrowing from Latin. Etymon: Latin *pudentia*.
>
> **Etymology**: < post-classical Latin *pudentia* modesty (5th cent. in Augustine) < classical Latin *pudent*- , *pudēns* pudent adj. + -*ia* -y suffix3; compare -ency suffix. Compare earlier ***pudicity*** n.
>
> Modesty, bashfulness, or reticence; embarrassment; an instance or expression of this.

For *pudicity* meaning shamefulness (so the opposite of *impudicity* meaning shamelessness), the OED gives:

> ## *pudicity*
>
> **Etymology**: Partly < Middle French *pudicité* modesty, chastity, behaviour which shows a sense of shame (1417; French *pudicité* ; < *pudique* **pudic** adj. + -*ité* -ity suffix, after classical Latin *pudīcitia*), and partly < classical Latin *pudīcitia* sexual purity, chastity < *pudīcus* **pudic** adj. + -*itia* -ity suffix. Compare Italian *pudicizia* (a1292).
>
> Modesty, decency; chastity.

And also places *pudicity* in the same Frequency Band Two as it places *pudency*, a band for fairly rare words in English that most people will not know. So most people would understand neither of those two lovely Latin loanwords lost to a time when any educated English speaker was also literate in at least Latin if not also something like French or Italian. This is no longer true.

That means it won’t do you any good to tease out some nuance of difference between them, or with any of the several other terms ultimately deriving from the same Latin etymon, like *pudor, pudic, pudify, pudibundery, pudendous, pudor, pudent, pudeur*. Those are all much too “fancy” for anything except the most technical of texts, preferably one that gets to define its own terminology.

Comment: Yes, from looking up "pudency" and finding out it comes from Latin "to shame" made me think of "pudenda", which I surprisingly found comes from the same "shame" meaning. Shame on me for my impure thoughts.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see that sticking to those pu* words was definitely a mistake. Now I am more interested to find the right word instead. The selection you give is a good start, thatk you again!

Comment: @C-F Your welcome. Those *pud-* words are all either immediately recognizable **to me personally,** but only because I am ridiculously over-educated in half a dozen Romance languages that almost no English monoglot by definition knows anything about. So they won't see the connections the way I personally would.

Comment: @Zebrafish Now consider the connection between *impudent* and *pudent*. For most people, the *pudent*  in *impudent* is a cranberry morpheme, not a word in its own right.

Comment: tchrist, please may I worship at your feet?